# Can missing QSOs in my contest log adversely affect other operator's scores?

Tags: contest, logging

I worked a little of the NA RTTY QSO Party and messed up logging for the first couple QSOs. I have the callsign and exchange data, but can only guess at time and band.

My question is whether missing QSO entries in my log could penalize the other operators for those QSOs. If I submitted no log at all, they would not be penalized. I don't know of a way of logging a QSO, but leaving out certain data fields (like time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sending a log with missing QSOs would lead to penalties for those of your QSO partners who are sending a log themselves. There is no way sensible way of "logging" a QSO with incomplete details, as that would defy the purpose. However, regarding time: if the possible "window" is only a few minutes anyway, then guessing time may be good enough. Most contest checkers give a bit of leeway, +/- 5 minutes say, to account for non-accurate clocks (penalties for time differences appear to grow less, though, since so many operators nowadays need accurate computer clocks for the latest digimodes).

Comment: Thanks for the information - it sounds like it would be better for me not to submit logs this time. I just dabble in contests anyhow, but sometimes submit logs as "check logs" since it is encouraged to help the scoring.

It would be nice if there was a Cabrillo header where you could indicate an incomplete log, particularly if you are submitting as a check log.